# Keep FTP in sync with local folder in Ububtu

Tags: ubuntu, sync, ftp

I've been searching  for about an hour and cant find what I want so i ask here.

Is there a way, except mounting FTP as drive, in Ubuntu to watch the local folder for changes, then reflect those changes to FTP server immediately.

For example I open a file from local folder, edit it, save it and then it gets uploaded to my FTP automatically.

Something like "Synchronize" in WinSCP.